# Rearranging elements in a table

Tags: html, css

I want to arrange the text like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmTmT.png) but I didn't figure out how I would do this, by only using css. I tried using margin but it didn't work. The problem is that over the whole table it looks scuffed.

```
.ttps-span-left {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10%;
}


.ttps-span-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.ttps-span-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/momonunu/pen/RwVeeQy

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that others may help you with your issue

Comment: https://codepen.io/momonunu/pen/RwVeeQy

Comment: Please provide all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site like CodePen. See [ask], where it says "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set li element as css grid, and remove margins, padding from spans:

```
li {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 0 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because the default margin was on **ul**.

Use this instead:

```
.ttps-lesson ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  /* ADDED HERE */
  margin: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `'display: flex'` and `'justify-content: space-around'` on the `.ttps-lesson ul li` class and some other tweaks to get somewhat the similar result you are looking for.

https://codepen.io/SL0TR/pen/ExmddMX

Updates:

```
   .ttps-lesson {
     position: relative;
    }

    .ttps-lesson ul li {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .ttps-lesson ul li span {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: kinda works but accepted answer was better, but ty

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox is the best/easiest way to lay this out and also make it more dynamic.

```
<ul class="flex">
 <li class="flexitem main">
 <li class="flexitem">
 <li class="flexitem">
</ul>
<style>
 .flex {display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;//other flex options}
 .flexitem {width:33%;}
 .main {font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

Comment: sry, but only css